# How can I view the output of `git show` in a diff viewer like meld, kdiff3, etc

Tags: git, version-control, diff, dvcs

There are many SO questions that show how to view the output of a `git diff` command in a diff viewer like meld using `git difftool` or otherwise.  I am not asking about `git diff` though.

I want to see the output of `git show <previous commit sha1>` in a diff viewer like meld. How can I do this?

Comment: `gitk`, `gitg`, and others come to mind...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use `git difftool` to show a single commit.

Say you want to see the commit with the sha1 `abc123`:

```
git difftool abc123~1 abc123
```

(`~1` tells git to move to the previous commit, so `abc123~1` is the commit before `abc123`)

If you use this regularly, you could make a custom git command to make it easier:

1. Create a file called `git-showtool` somewhere on your `$PATH` with the following contents:

   ```
   git difftool $1~1 $1
   ```
2. Give that file execute permissions:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/path/to/git-showtool
   ```
3. Use the command `git showtool <sha1 or tag or ...>`
4. Profit.

Comment: also, you should cross-check what commit you are going to view and whether it contains many changed files. because meld is going to open one after the other consecutively

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error.

Launch 'p4mergetool' [Y/n]? Y
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: eval: line 124: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: eval: line 125: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: `git show $commit` is not equivalent to `git difftool $commit~1 $commit` if we are reviewing a merge commit. git show presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by `git diff-tree --cc $commit`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show

Comment: You can use the `^` to do parent commits also like `git difftool abc123^ abc123`. Apply multiple times to go up the tree higher like `abc123^^^`

Comment: Somebody should merge this nice and simple tool to mainline git

Answer (score 31):

Building on georgebrock's response, you can create an alias in .gitconfig, something like this:

```
showtool = "!showci () { rev=${1:-HEAD}; git difftool $rev~1 $rev; }; showci $1"
```

Then you can run it with `git showtool abc123` (without needing to create a separate shell script for this).  If you leave out the revision it will default to HEAD.

Comment: I agree a git alias would probably be better. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I strongly prefer this solution :) And I passed --dir-diff to the difftool command to be even more convenient for me.

Answer (score 15):

Translating sagittarian's suggestion for the less git savvy, add this to your global **.gitconfig** file which resides in **C:\Users[user name]** if you are a windows user:

```
[alias]
    showtool = "!showci () { rev=${1:-HEAD}; git difftool $rev~1 $rev; }; showci $1"
```

or you can execute the following command in the get bash shell:

```
git config --global alias.showtool '!showci () { rev=${1:-HEAD}; git difftool $rev~1 $rev; }; showci $1'
```

which will make the change to the **.gitconfig** file for you.

Answer (score 5):

Building on sagitarrian's answer, here's a small change for more generic rev syntax:

```
showtool = "!showci () { rev=$(git rev-parse \"${*:-HEAD}\"); git difftool $rev~1 $rev; }; showci"
```

I use `rev-parse` to transparently allow complex rev expressions.

I removed the `$1` at the end, since the alias is called followed by the arguments; it passes unnoticed when using only `$1` but breaks `$*` behaviour.

This allows doing nice things like:

```
git showtool :/some nasty bug
```

Comment: Equivalent shell command: `git config --global alias.showtool '!showci () { rev=$(git rev-parse "${*:-HEAD}"); git difftool $rev~1 $rev; }; showci'`
(I wasn't able to suggest the edit)

Answer (score 2):

Geogrebrock answer is fine, but can be improved thus:

```
commit=$1
shift
git difftool $commit~1 $commit $@
```

Put it in executable (chmod +x) file somewhere in $PATH.

Now you can pass additional arguments, for example specify what files you want to see (and ignore others):

```
$ git showtool 6a40ec6ffb9338b0548aefab92fded1bffb1648a -- src-cmn/
```

Answer (score 1):

The `git-showcommit` file (executable) in the PATH should be as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

git difftool --dir-diff $1^..$1
```

then you can simply call the new tool by `git showcommit HEAD` or `git showcommit a5b26d5`